# Change I2C address Linux driver kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, i2c

I have a system which uses module Sensors LM75 with two I2C adresses (0x48 and 0x49). I'd like to cancel one address (0x48), however I don't understand where there is its initialisation.

All changes in normal_i2c , are not relevant ....

```
/* Addresses scanned */
static const unsigned short normal_i2c[] = { 0x48, 0x49, 0x4a, 0x4b, 0x4c,
                    0x4d, 0x4e, 0x4f, I2C_CLIENT_END };
```

Comment: Did your post get cut? It appears there's missing information about that normal_i2c (where is it from?). What have you already tried?

Comment: normal_i2c[] - it is array in lm75.c . I thought that the driver gets i2c address from this array . But it's not right.

Answer (score 3):

The driver [`lm75.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/hwmon/lm75.c) registers itself with the kernel as a handler for ALL i2c devices with any of the 7bit addresses listed in `normal_i2c` array.

```
/* Addresses scanned */
static const unsigned short normal_i2c[] = { 0x48, 0x49, 0x4a, 0x4b, 0x4c,
0x4d, 0x4e, 0x4f, I2C_CLIENT_END };
```

Next, the array is **[pointed to by struct `lm75_driver`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/hwmon/lm75.c#L489)** (of type `i2c_driver`)

```
.address_list   = normal_i2c,
```

Also note that the `class` and `detect` members of the `i2c_driver` struct are initialised appropriately

```
.class          = I2C_CLASS_HWMON,
.detect         = lm75_detect,
```

- various options for `.class` are listed [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/i2c.h#L564).
- `.detect` is a function that will be called whenever a new i2c-bus or i2c-driver is being initialised.

When the driver registers with the Linux kernel, [this `i2c_driver` struct is passed on to the Linux kernel](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/hwmon/lm75.c#L563) (with the list of i2c addresses to be associated with this driver).

```
module_i2c_driver(lm75_driver);
```

**At runtime, what occurs next is summarised in the following call-graph:**

> [`i2c_register_driver()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/i2c/i2c-core.c#L1863)
>
> > [`__process_new_adapter()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/i2c/i2c-core.c#L1521)
> >
> > > [`i2c_do_add_adapter()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/i2c/i2c-core.c#L1503)
> > >
> > > > [`i2c_detect()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/i2c/i2c-core.c#L2443)
> > > >
> > > > > [`lm75_detect()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/hwmon/lm75.c#L359)  *called using `driver->detect()`*

The `lm75_detect()` function contains the device-specific logic to determine whether an i2c device detected on the current i2c bus should be handled by the current driver (in this case `lm75.c`) or not.

> For automatic device detection, both `detect` and `address_list` must be defined. `class` should also be set, otherwise **only** devices forced with module parameters will be created.
>
> The detect function must fill at least the name field of the `i2c_board_info` structure it is handed upon successful detection, and possibly also the `flags` field.

Comment: Hi, I have a board with TMP75 temp sensor on a i2c bus, which is handled by lm75 driver. It's at the address 0x4a. I'm loading the driver and it's getting loaded but it is not detecting the device. In the /sys/bus/i2c/drivers/lm75/ , I see only following files/folder : `bind`  `module`  `uevent`  `unbind`. I don't see any other entry where possibly the temp_input etc. device attributes are present. Not sure how do I debug this further..